# Adding Video/s in an existing Tkinter Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-import, opencv

I would like to add a looping video in a tkinter window. I have seen codes from here in stacksoverflow and online, and they seem to be about a Live Capture Video. in my case, I would like to import a video file to my existing Tkinter window, and if possible, keep it on loop. what modules do I need to import and how do I structure the code properly?

I am gonna add some codes that I have used.. I thankfully give the credits to the original creators whoever they are.

```
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


video_name = "vid.mp4"
video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)


def stream(label):

    for image in video.iter_data():
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    my_label = Label(root)
    my_label.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target = stream, args=(my_label))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Just curious, can't you just wrap your `stream(label)` function with a `while` loop?

Comment: Aran-Fey: it's working, but my goal is to add the video into an existing tkinter window.. that code makes a new window.

Comment: Henry Yik: Hi, i'm a beginner at Python. what would stream(label) do?