# Can I add a video in my tkinter window? And can I resize the video?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I want to add 60 FPS mp4 files in my Tkinter window. I also want to resize them to make them the appropriate size for the window. Further, put them on loop. First, is this possible in Python? and second, how can I start?

I find myself having the same unanswered question as this fellow: [Adding Video/s in an existing Tkinter Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312744/adding-video-s-in-an-existing-tkinter-window)

Comment: Considering there's a [whole GitHub project for that](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer), it doesn't sound trivial, and considering [they couldn't even get sound to work](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/issues/2), it sounds like there's no free lunch here.

Comment: @RandomDavis looks like I'll have to wait then. Sound is not my concern. Based on the 120 FPS issue, I should wait till the developer updates the project.

Comment: You might be waiting a long time. There's no guarantee that project is going to go anywhere. I suggest looking at alternatives; see if there's *any* library that'll let you play video via Python in a window that you control.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks for the suggestion. This seems promising https://github.com/huskeee/tkvideo Ill try it out and get back to here for future reference